# Partition existing table on non-primary key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have an existing table "Case_details" with below columns:

- Case_ref `varchar` (PK)
- Case_name `varchar`
- Status `varchar`
- Archive_date `Datetime`

I want to partition this table based on _Archive_date_. I have created a partition function and partition scheme already. I just need to partition the above existing table! What are the steps to do it?

Comment: @Syed . . . I would recommend setting up the table with partitions *before* loading data into it.  In other words, move the data into the right partitions the first time.  That said, databases that support partitioning let you add and remove partitions which is probably what you need to do.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff, but the table which i am using consist of millions of rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it is an existing table. so i just need to alter it. What is the safer way to do it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i am using sql server 2016